# frozen while loading data for a Viewpager using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter

In my code, I have an activity with a button that calls another activity with a viewpager and within this, three fragments.

```
//...
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

ViewPagerAdapter adapterViewPager = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapterViewPager.addFragment(new FragmentOne());
        adapterViewPager.addFragment(new FragmentTwo());
        adapterViewPager.addFragment(new FragmentThree());

        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        pager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

//..
```

on pages / fragments, there is a listview that loads data (images and text) from the internet, load this data using AsyncTask

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

//...
    public class loadEntries extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        //...

        public String doInBackground(String... urls){
            String url = urls[0];

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return xml;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(String xml){
            try{
                entrieList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                Document doc = getDomElement(xml); 

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ENTRIE);

                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                    map.put(KEY_ID_ENTRIE, getValue(e, KEY_ID_ENTRIE));
                    map.put(KEY_IMAGE_ENTRIE,getValue(e, KEY_IMAGE_ENTRIE));
                    map.put(KEY_TEXT_ENTRIE, getValue(e, KEY_TEXT_ENTRIE));

                    entrieList.add(map);
                }
                theListViewAdapter();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Exception
            }
        }
    }
//...
```

In each ListView Adapter I'm using to expedite the process ViewHolder:

```
//...
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_gallery_web, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text_one = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.titleImageItemGalleryWeb); 
        holder.image_row=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageItemGalleryWeb);

        HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();
        items = data.get(position);

        try { 
            String textentrie = new String(items.get(FRG_gallery_web.KEY_TITLE_IMAGE).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            holder.text_one.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml(textentrie));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(items.get(FRG_gallery_web.KEY_URL_IMAGE), holder.image_row);
        return vi;
    }
```

**This is my problem:**

When I press the button that calls the activity containing the viewpager, everything freezes while loading the fragments. The background processes are working properly because I can read the logs correctly.
To try to explain it better, if I press the button that calls the activity containing the viewpager, show on screen a progressbar, this also freezes.

I'm loading data from internet in other threads, other than the principal of each fragment.

What is the reason that a freeze while charging?

I appreciate any help.

Thank you. Regards